Prometheus target give 403 error in OTEL collector Permanent error: remote write returned HTTP status 403 Forbidden;
Authneticaiotn Error (403) for export matrix data from OTEL Collector to Prometheus.
here mentioned the required details of otel-collector.yaml file's like exporters and service part for the referance.
Basically i, try to send the matrics data to the aws prometheus but the prometheus endpoint gives authentication error.
below are the way by using that i try to resolve the authetication issue but it was't work.
i also try with the sigV4 aws protocol but i am not much aware about sigV4.
1)
exporters:  
  prometheusremotewrite: 
   endpont : <aws-read/write endpoint value>
   auth:
      authenticator: sigv4auth
      aws_region: <aws-region-value>
      aws_access_key_id: <aws-access-key-value>
      aws_secret_access_key: <aws-secret-access-key-value>

2)
exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: <aws-read/write endpoint value>
    auth:
      authenticator: aws

extensions:
  awsproxy:
    region: "us-east-1"

service:
  extensions: [awsproxy]
  pipelines:


Blockquote

    metrics:
      receivers: [prometheus]
      exporters: [prometheusremotewrite]
 

